# Guava Graph library ElementOrder on Edges instead of Nodes

Tags: guava, graph-algorithm, mutablemap

I have this straight-forward **Graph structure** using the [Guava Graph library](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/GraphsExplained) and I'd like to understand better if that is possible to sort the `adjacents/edges` (not the `node` order). For the sake of clarification:

```
import com.google.common.graph.ElementOrder;
import com.google.common.graph.GraphBuilder;
import com.google.common.graph.MutableGraph;

public class MyNodeTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MutableGraph<String> graph = GraphBuilder.undirected().nodeOrder(ElementOrder.insertion()).build();

        graph.addNode("A");
        graph.addNode("C");
        graph.addNode("D");
        graph.addNode("B");
        graph.addNode("E");

        graph.putEdge("A", "B");
        graph.putEdge("A", "C");
        graph.putEdge("A", "D");
        graph.putEdge("A", "E");

        System.out.println("My default Insertion.order Nodes: " + graph.nodes());
        System.out.println("Adj. Order that I couldn't understand: " + graph.adjacentNodes("A"));
        System.out.println("Successor. Order that I couldn't understand: " + graph.successors("A"));
        System.out.println("Pred. Order that I couldn't understand: " + graph.predecessors("A"));
    }
}
```

My outcome is:

```
My default Insertion.order Nodes: [A, C, D, B, E]
Adj. Order that I couldn't understand: [D, E, B, C]
Successor. Order that I couldn't understand: [D, E, B, C]
Pred. Order that I couldn't understand: [D, E, B, C]
```

Without further ado, what I mean is:

Using `.nodeOrder(ElementOrder.insertion())` it is possible to sort the nodes themselves. Nonetheless, I'm more interested in sorting the `edges` associated with a given `node` in a way that if I used the `putEdge` respectively from `A` with `B, C, D, E` the outcome is precisely this instead of the above shown.

Any insight?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: So there's no `edgeOrder` method, right? In fact, the developers of this library could easily add that feature for edges as well. I suspect they are populating `LinkedHashSet` for nodes, if `nodeOrder(ElementOrder.insertion())` is specified

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case someone faces the same question, here is how I solved it (disclaimer: not the optimal, but a working solution).

```
    MutableNetwork<String, UUID> graph = NetworkBuilder.undirected().edgeOrder(ElementOrder.insertion()).build();

    graph.addNode("A");
    graph.addNode("C");
    graph.addNode("D");
    graph.addNode("B");
    graph.addNode("E");

    graph.addEdge("A", "B", UUID.randomUUID());
    graph.addEdge("A", "C", UUID.randomUUID());
    graph.addEdge("A", "D", UUID.randomUUID());
    graph.addEdge("A", "E", UUID.randomUUID());

    System.out.println("My default Insertion.order Nodes: " + graph.nodes());
    System.out.println("Adj. Order that I couldn't understand: " + graph.adjacentNodes("A"));
    System.out.println("Successor. Order that I couldn't understand: " + graph.successors("A"));
    System.out.println("Pred. Order that I couldn't understand: " + graph.predecessors("A"));
```

And the results:

```
My default Insertion.order Nodes: [A, C, D, B, E]
Adj. Order that I couldn't understand: [B, C, D, E]
Successor. Order that I couldn't understand: [B, C, D, E]
Pred. Order that I couldn't understand: [B, C, D, E]
```

The `MutableNetwork` has the `.edgeOrder(ElementOrder.insertion())` that does the trick. The cons here are associated with the `K,V` needed to create this data structure.

Regards